# ListLogPlot does not show vertical line

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I was trying to plot a vertical line using ListPlot everything works perfectly:

```
MassPeaks = {{9.1, 0}, {9.1, 2}};
ListPlot[MassPeaks, Joined -> True]
```

However, if I change ListPlot to ListLogPlot my line disappears:

```
ListLogPlot[MassPeaks, Joined -> True]
```

shows the same axes but no line. Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Since `Log[0]` evaluates to `Infinity` you need a value close to `0`.
You also should specify `PlotRange` to get a "nice" scaling.

```
ListLogPlot[{{9.1, 2}, {9.1, 0.00001}},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.1, 4}}]
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
ListLogPlot[{{9.1, 2}}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]